# How can I get on click event on PreferenceCategory's tilte?

Tags: android-preferences

I tried but it not called OnPreferenceClickListener. Seem like it only works with normal Preference, not PreferenceCategory.

```
   PreferenceCategory advanceScreen = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("pref_category_advanced");

    advanceScreen.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preference categories are not clickable - so they won't receive click events, or show a ripple - is there a reason you want a category to be clickable?